# Direct image of the structure sheaf of $X\times\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective variety, $Y=X\times\mathbb{P}^1$ and $p:Y\to X$ be a projection. Since the dimension of fibres of $p$ is equal to one we have $R^ip_*\mathcal{O}_Y=0$ for $i>1$. Is it true in general that $R^1p_*\mathcal{O}_Y=0$ and $p_*\mathcal{O}_Y=\mathcal{O}_X$?

If it is not, what about the case $X=\mathbb{P}^1$?

Comment: If $U$ is an open set in $X$, a regular function on $p^{-1}(U)$ has to be constant along the fibers of $p$, since its restriction to each such fiber is a regular function on $P^1$.

Comment: Does this mean that $p_*\mathcal{O}_Y=\mathcal{O}_X$?

Comment: Well, what is the definition of $p_*(\mathcal O_Y)$?

Comment: On every open $V\subset X$ it is defined as $\mathcal{O}_Y(p^{-1}(V))$.

Comment: So, does anyone know the answer?

Comment: Have you seen Exercise III.8.4 in Hartshorne?